# GPU-"Proof" Hash Function(s)?

Tags: hash, cuda, p2p, gpgpu, cpu-architecture

I am thinking about designing a p2p network that requires a certain level of proof-of-work for vetting of users (similar to bitcoin) and regulation of spam/ddos.  Due to the nature of p2p, the only feasible POW architecture I have seen is the solution-verification model.  Other models (challenge-response) seem very prone to a Sybil attack, so I am not considering them.

Hash-reversal seems to be an excellent way to go, but the issue of GPU hashing ruins the fairness of the protocol by several orders of magnitude. Due to this, I am trying to identify hash algorithms that are difficult/infeasible to accelerate beyond the capabilities of a modern, multi-core CPU by using a GPU.

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My Cuckoo Cycle proof-of-work scheme seems to fit the bill, as it is 5%
computation and 95% random access to global shared memory, incurring long
latencies.
GPU memory is limited and has much worse latencies, and there's not enough
computation to keep more than a few dozen gpu-cores busy.

Other features: it can require any desired amount of RAM, and is instantly verifiable.

See https://github.com/tromp/cuckoo for a whitepaper and implementation.

Comment: Interesting, but the big question is, does it cut it as a cryptographic hashing algorithm, or are there any weaknesses?

Comment: It's not a hashing algorithm. Perhaps http://cryptorials.io/beyond-hashcash-proof-work-theres-mining-hashing (there’s more to mining than hashing) explains your confusion...

Answer (score 2):

Its all an arms race - while currently deployed hash functions are easy to GPU accelerate, and newer/larger/longer hash functions are not (due to current hardware limits), as technology marches on newer and better hardware will be available.

My first recommendation would be to have the application provide "hash suites", identified by a positive integer. As time goes on, you can switch to newer and more expensive operations and have new software stop accepting proofs from lower-numbered hash suites.

Also, be non-traditional. Perhaps use a combination of all of the new SHA-3 candidates (all of them, in some cascading series). Use block-cipher-hash algorithms (AES can be turned into an impromptu hash function). Do a large number of rounds. Perhaps require signing by very large RSA keys (4096 bit and beyond, and require unique "throw-away" keys).

You're buying time, so the deprecation mechanism is substantially more important than the actual algorithm choice.

Comment: I have located what seems to be a pretty good candidate so far... http://www.usenix.org/event/usenix99/provos/provos_html/node4.html

The key schedule is variable so difficulty can be increased in time, and each execution requires 4KB of memory for the S-box, so GPUs should have a very hard time dealing with this in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend something like BCrypt where the hashing function has a variable number of rounds, usually in the thousands. As long as the hashing function at the core of the algorithm remains secure, it can be made more resistant to brute force as time progresses by simply incrementing the number of rounds.